# Django ORM Optimisation - annotating by count as well as the last entry for the annotate filter

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I currently have the following property on a `Post` model:

```
@property
def compliments(self):
    compliments_by_kind = list(
        self.compliment_set.values(
            'kind'
        ).annotate(
            amount=Count('kind')
        ).values(
            'kind',
            'amount'
        )
    )

    for compliment_by_kind in compliments_by_kind:
        compliment_by_kind['last_giver'] = self.compliment_set.filter(
            kind=compliment_by_kind['kind']
        ).order_by(
            'created'
        ).last().giver.name

    return compliments_by_kind
```

This returns the following listing data structure:

```
[
  {
    'kind': 'unique', 
    'amount': 3, 
    'last_giver': 'Person 1'
  }, 
  {
    'kind': 'fresh', 
    'amount': 2, 
    'last_giver': 'Person 2'
  }, 
  {
    'kind': 'concept', 
    'amount': 3, 
    'last_giver': 'Person 3'
  }, 
  {
    'kind': 'lines', 
    'amount': 1, 
    'last_giver': 'Person 4'
  }
]
```

There's nothing wrong with the data, per se. There's just nothing right with ther performance of performing Queries within the loop.

However, the looping method - is not efficient - for each kind (which there are 6 in total, there are 6 further queries on top of the one to get the `Count` annotation. So, this really hampers performance on the `serialization` stage.

Would anyone know how to perform the `annotation` for the latest `Compliment` "`giver.name`" according to the ordering by "`created`" attribute according the the "kind" ... i.e., the last person to give a compliment of "kind" unique etc etc

Here is the `Compliment` model:

```
class Compliment(TimeStampedModel):
    giver = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="giver",
    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="receiver",
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    kind = models.CharField(choices=COMPLIMENTS_CHOICES, max_length=15)
```

UPDATE: **Utilising Willem's brilliant suggestion, the solution for me was:**

```
@property
def compliments(self):
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

    compliments_by_kind = list(
        self.compliment_set.values(
            'kind'
        ).annotate(
            amount=Count('kind'),
            first_name=Subquery(
                get_user_model().objects.filter(
                    giver__artwork_id=self.pk,
                    giver__kind=OuterRef('kind')
                ).values('first_name').order_by('-giver__created')[:1]
            ),
            last_name=Subquery(
                get_user_model().objects.filter(
                    giver__artwork_id=self.pk,
                    giver__kind=OuterRef('kind')
                ).values('last_name').order_by('-giver__created')[:1]
            ),
        )
    )

    return compliments_by_kind
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant models (of the `Compliment`s, and the one that relates to the `.giver`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No problem at all - added. The `giver` relates to standard Django `User` model. The `kind` is purely a Char string, assume any number of `CHOICES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the `last_giver` in the same query (and thus avoid the *N+1 problem*), by using a `Subquery`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

compliments_by_kind = list(
    self.compliment_set.values(
        'kind'
    ).annotate(
        amount=Count('kind')
        last_name=Subquery(
            get_user_model().objects.filter(
                giver__post_id=self.pk,
                giver__kind=OutRef('kind')
            ).values('name').order_by('giver__created')[:1]
        )
    )
)
```

That being said, as discussed in the comments, the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in "reverse", so the one to obtain the compliments a user has given or received. Therefore it might be better to rename these to:

```
class Compliment(TimeStampedModel):
    giver = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='given_compliments',
    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='received_compliments',
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kind = models.CharField(choices=COMPLIMENTS_CHOICES, max_length=15)
```

Then the query looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

compliments_by_kind = list(
    self.compliment_set.values(
        'kind'
    ).annotate(
        amount=Count('kind')
        last_name=Subquery(
            get_user_model().objects.filter(
                given_compliments__post_id=self.pk,
                given_compliments__kind=OutRef('kind')
            ).values('name').order_by('giver__created')[:1]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `.order_by('giver__created')` is not quite right - it needs to be `ordered_by` the last compliment of that kind...

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts: but that is happening. Because you have set `related_name` to `'giver'` as well (this is the name of the relation from `User` to `Compliment`, so the relation in "reverse"). It thus uses the `created` of the `Compliment`. But I agree that the `related_name` can be improved.

Comment: Awesome - I’ll test it at length tomorrow. I’ve clocked off for the day- but it’s looking promising.

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you very much for this considered answer. I kept the related names the same, giver and receiver, as this may have introduced a breaking change to my code base. With that said, with one slight tweak ... `.order_by('-giver__created')[:1]` ... giving me not the last person to `Compliment` but the latest, has given me what I want. I would state this slight change was more down to my explaination than anything else.

Comment: One minor question tho Willem - can I somehow concatenate the `first_name` and `last_name` somehow for the solution I added to my question?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts: probably by replacing `values('name')` with `values(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'))` (with `from django.db.models.functions import Concat` and `from django.db.models import Value`).